# What does this oddly syntaxed C++ code with mean?

Tags: c++

I came across this code and I can not make sense of it.

```
RegisterCallback(MgrTsk::NAME,                                                                                                               
    [=](uint16_t cmd, uint16_t value, uint32_t size, void* pData) -> bool     {                                                              
        return MsgFromTsk(cmd, size, pData);                                                                                             
});
```

The return type of `MsgFromTsk` is `bool`. The API for `RegisterCallback` is -

```
template<typename F>                                                                                                                          
void RegisterCallback(const char* procName, F msgCallback)
```

This probably might be a simple question, but even after a lot of google-ing I couldn't understand the syntax.

Comment: Which part of this confuses you? Do you know the lambda syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: It's a *lambda* function with *trailing return type* syntax.

Comment: @UnholySheep I was unaware on the lambda syntax, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lambda:

```
[=](uint16_t cmd, uint16_t value, uint32_t size, void* pData) -> bool     {                                                              
    return MsgFromTsk(cmd, size, pData);                                                                                             
}
```

- `[...]` is the capture-list of the lambda,
- The `=`in `[=]` means that by default, the lambda captures variables by value,
- `(...)` are the parameters passed to the lambda,
- `-> bool` is the return type of the lambda,
- `{...}`is the body of the lambda

Answer (score 1):

In the call to `RegisterCallback` in the first block you posted, that function is called with `MgrTsk::NAME` as a first argument and

```
 [=](uint16_t cmd, uint16_t value, uint32_t size, void* pData) -> bool {                                                              
    return MsgFromTsk(cmd, size, pData);}
```

as a second argument.

Thas is, the template parameter `F` is now a lambda that takes `uint16_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, void*` as arguments and returns `bool`, and it calls `MsgFromTsk` to determine the returned value.